# Write generic multi-dimensional Map type

Tags: typescript, generics, variadic

I'd like to create a generic multi-dimensional map type where the last of N types is the final value and the preceding types will effectively be a key.

In other words:

```
let m:MDMap<Coat,Pie,Date,Location>;

//...

m.get(myWoolCoat,myApplePie,yesterday) // returns a Location
```

Without variadic generics though it looks like I'm going to end up with something like this:

```js
export type MultiMap<
    A extends any,
    B extends any,
    C = void,
    D = void,
    // ... etc.
> = D extends void 
      ? C extends void 
          ? Map<A,B>
          : Map<A,Map<B,C>>
      : Map<A,Map<B,Map<C,D>>>

let m:MultiMap<Coat,Pie,Date,Location>;
```

I know Typescript handles variadic *tuple* types but I haven't been able to bridge that ability to something resembling the above desire.

Should I make do with the work-around or is there some way to pull off some kind recursive generic?

Comment: There are no variadic generics; but you can use tuple types instead, like `MultiMap<[Coat, Pie, Date], Location>` or maybe `MultiMap<[Coat, Pie, Date, Location]>` (the former seems more correct to me though).  You can certainly make a recursive generic that makes that an alias for `Map<Coat, Map<Pie, Map<Date, Location>>>`, but that doesn't magically produce a `get()` method which takes three key parameters.  Could you clarify exactly what you're looking for here?  Is it a `MultiMap` implementation or a way to recursively define a `MultiMap` type in terms of nested `Map`s?

Comment: Just the type. I could be wrong but it seems if that's in-hand then getting a properly typed implementation of get and set is no problem, whereas if I can't even write a type for a nested set of Maps of unknown depth, then I'm not going to get a properly typed get and set later. At least that's my experience so far.

Comment: I've been poking at a recursive generic but I may just be a dim crayon today. I'll keep looking in that direction.

Comment: So like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkMV1N), then?  I'm happy to write up how that works (as long as it doesn't expand in scope for how you actually implement the thing).

Comment: That's it! I'd love details! FWIW, the infer and ...infer is the greek part — the rest I follow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have variadic generics, so there's no way to write something like `MultiMap<...K, V>` meaning that there is some arbitrary number of key type parameters and one value type parameter.  But, as you note, there *are* [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) which can hold an arbitrary ordered list of types, so you might be satisfied with `MultiMap<K, V>` where the `K` is a tuple.  So instead of `MultiMap<Coat, Pie, Date, Location>` you'd write `MultiMap<[Coat, Pie, Date], Location>`.  It's just a few more characters anyway.

As for making `MultiMap<[Coat, Pie, Date], Location>` resolve to `Map<Coat, Map<Pie, Map<Date, Location>>>`, we can do that by defining `MultiMap<K, V>` as a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) where we use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to pull apart the `K` tuple into its first element `F` and the rest of the tuple `R`:

```
type MultiMap<K extends any[], V> = K extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    Map<F, MultiMap<R, V>> : V;
```

The syntax `K extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? XXX : YYY` is known as [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) where we can bring new type parameters into scope by having the compiler infer them.  `K extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? XXX : YYY` means that we want the compiler to try to match `K` to a variadic tuple with some initial element `F` and some rest element `R`.  If it works, then inside the `XXX` type expression, `F` will be the first element type and `R` will be a shorter tuple representing the rest.  That is, if `K` is `[Coat, Pie, Date]` then `F` will be `Coat` and `R` will be `[Pie, Date]`. And hence `Map<F, MultiMap<R, V>>` will be `Map<Coat, MultiMap<[Pie, Date], V>>` and you can see the recursion happen.  If `K` is an empty tuple, then we have no keys at all and we just use `V`, so that the base case of the recursion terminates how we want.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type MyMap = MultiMap<[Coat, Pie, Date], Location>;
// type MyMap = Map<Coat, Map<Pie, Map<Date, Location>>>
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgG2ASxgQzAHgNJQgD2AgDsATAZyjWJAG0BdAGigDUA+KAXilwKLMq1kxAGYQATlABizAHTzhYyQCV6UAPwBYAFBQ9sDJhmxEKdFmXN2HAFysA3Dp2hIsEOa4mkqQ7QDCAPZowMwACsgQzAAiwRBMUAAyAQDGwcgBxGyO2gD0OVAu0DDuGJ7mmIHBzOXhkQZYMUTMSakoGWwdTtrCROIiaMnQlcBQAN46+lDkyABeEHbEcAC2AEYS2QC+Oj0S-YNQtWMT+oV25MDiwgDmm9vEvXvQLWkZR7r6CMELy2vi2ZMIYhXb6rdY6LbaHRAA)